# Can't I access Features from MMF directly

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

Please Need Help on this,
As I can access user stories from feature by saying

feature is an PortfolioItem/Feature object

```
feature.get('UserStories')
```

Can't I access features from PortfolioItem/MMF directly

Any suggestions on this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a position to test this myself, but try getting the 'Children' attribute on the MMF

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actully I tried this but children is null. But it has 4 features.

Comment: Children is the correct field.  If you can post some code for how you are trying to access the children we can probably help further...

Comment: below is the code I tried to access MMF features, selectedRecord is a PortfolioItem/MMF object                     'console.log("children value", selectedRecord.get('Children'));'    See the below image u can see Children "" and DirectChildrenCount is 4      (http://postimg.org/image/kourxeyzj/452cb2f6/)

Comment: I don't see your code. But if you are looking at the object'd dump in the DevTools and Children is empty, perhaps you are not fetching Children attribute.